# Valid MYSQL SELECT Query not working on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, quotes

Ok, so here is my headache:

I got a database that contains a lot of texts (big ones) and I am running a VALID MYSQL query.

I wont post the BIG text here because it is useless, lets do the following.

My PHP is listening on UDP por 8000
My software connects to PHP via this UDP port and sends it what it needs to search for:

So I created this test to ilustrate:

Database name: test,
Table name: test,
Column: wtf.

[image: TEST DB DATA]

I run my PHP *LISTENING ON UDP*, my software sends

[image: The data]

and PHP receives it OK and runs the query based on this input.

Ç " ' <> /p  ----- !! ///

Data OK!!!!, so it RUNS the following query | select `wtf` FROM `test`.`test` where `wtf` = 'Ç " \' <> /p  ----- !! ///' limit 1 |

And you know what? This query is 100% VALID, lets see on HeidiSQL

but it looks like this query isn't good enough for PHP. The query is 100% Valid and if it run it on HeidiSQL, I get a Valid RESULT, but PHP keeps yelling that the result is null.

Comment: Stackoverflow didn't let me add more pics, but anyway, the query that my PHP tried to run is:

select `wtf` FROM `test`.`test` where `wtf` = 'Ç " \' <> /p <b> ----- !! ///' limit 1. And it is 1000000000% Valid, on HeidiSQL gives me a valid result. The string is escaped, everything fine. Looks like I will have to connect directly to the Database and forget PHP, because it is getting confused with Ç ~ "'''' etc

Comment: Good thing -- text is always better for code and such since it can be copy/pasted. But if you expect any help, you'll need to post the PHP code (in your question) that isn't working, along with any error messages you may be seeing. If no error messages, turn error reporting on.

Comment: I will have to recreate it in a simple way then, my php code is over 8000 lines, it is a 100% from scratch UDP Server using PHP and a lot of small C applications. No easy copypasta for me here, I am trying to do a fiddle, but thanks.

Comment: What does it do when using an ASCII character from [0-9][a-Z] instead of your query?

Comment: PHP Sucks, thats the deal, select * from `test`.`test` (OK HeidiSQL). PHP cannot select this it looks like. Geez so many problems with Encoding.

Comment: I added another row with the data "123" and select * from test.test returns only 1 row (123). Encoding issue.

Comment: Post relevant section(s) or a simplified sample/example of the code. That said, I'm surprised any kind of SQL Validator would say a query with "--" is okay, as that typically forces a comment on the rest of the line. If escaping that doesn't resolve the problem, then you might need to check your Collation. `Ç` is not represented in UTF-8, as far as I know, so your issue may be due to collation. If you are using the MySQLi module in your PHP, then you might need to do something like `$sql->set_charset("utf16")` in your code (you'll need to check if UTF-16 is appropriate for your database).

Comment: UTF-16 is the answer, it is returning now, and yeah the data is quite chaotic, but I didn't chose them :( so I have no choice. 
I always thought that UTF-8 included Ç and other characthers. Setting the database (that was set to UTF8) to UTF-16, and telling PHP to UTF-16 solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you Norbert and SpencerD!!!! Thanks guys!!!!